# Cloud Run - putting my microservices behind the Google Api Endpoint When using my own JWT not IAM

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, microservices

Folks,

I have microservices running as Google Cloud Run Services. I created an ESPv2 Proxy Gateway/Endpoint to protect my microservices.

My microservices are oAuth resource-server enabled and UI is passing JWT in every request. I setup OpenApi yaml file for my ESPv2 Gateway to handle custom authentication, not IAM, and put `disable_auth: true` to preserve my token when the request is passing to microservices.

The problem here is I want to keep my microservices private and not accessible from the public. If I deploy them by `--no--allow-unauthenticated` (gcloud run deploy SDK) then getting 401 probably because it expects to get IAM token not my own. If I deploy it by `--allow-unauthenticated` everything works but my microservice is exposed to the internet and I have DDoS attacks concerns (also for billing). Yes of course, my microservices are secured with oAuth but I don't want to be exposed to the internet as they are behind the gateway.

Also, I don't want to remove oAuth Resource-Server from my microservice code. I want to have my own security in place.

I know with Anthos platform I can make it internal access but I don't want to switch to Anthos for now (prefer managed platform)

Comment: Have you taken a look at this stack overflow post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52526854/how-to-set-up-custom-user-authentication-with-google-cloud-endpoints, It has information on setting up custom authentication with Oauth

Comment: this is different, I don't have a problem with custom auth.